# Run a new Hadoop streaming job from current running Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

Is it possible to create and run a new Hadoop **streaming** job from either

1. A regular Hadoop Java Job that's currently executing, or
2. A Hadoop Mapper (in Python) that's executing as part of a Hadoop streaming job.

and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most Java jobs it's simple to run a .jar within a Java program. Same with Python streaming jobs.

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input myInputDirs \
    -output myOutputDir \
    -mapper org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.IdentityMapper \
    -reducer /bin/wc